# Google Charts vAxis Values are not visible at first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am doing a project with the Google Charts API to make some column Chart graphs inside a clickable Tab-Panel.

I create the Google Chart with following jQuery-Event by click on the panel link.
Then the div size is calculated and the chart will be rendered.

```
$('.tab_link').click(function(){
   drawChart(get_Div_Size().width, get_Div_Size().height);
});
```

The code for the chart is:

```
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Geschlecht', 'Wert', { role: 'style' }, {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],
        ['Männer', 12.5, "#AFDBF5", null],
        ['Frauen', 8.8, "#D8645B", null],
        ['Ihre Eingabe', UserValue, "#4c4c4c", annotation]
    ]);

    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Vergleich'
          },
          vAxis: {
            gridlines: {color: '#333', count: 4},
            title: 'Distanz in Km',
        },
        legend: { position: "none" },
        width: width,
        height: height,
        title: 'Title',
        animation: {
            duration: 1500,
            startup: true
        }
    };




 chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart-1'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
```

Initially, the graph is rendered without problems like this:

[Graph without problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbddi.png)

If I click on another panel and re-click the first one the vAxis is missing:

[Graph missing vAxis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHSAd.png)

if i click the panel-link another time, the graph will generate properly.

Markup-structure for the panels:

```
            <div data-w-tab="Tab" class="tab_pane w-tab-pane w--tab-active">
          <div id="chart-1" class="chart_container"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-w-tab="Tab 2" class="tab_pane w-tab-pane">
          <div id="chart-2" class="chart_container"></div>
        </div>
```

Visually, the panel looks like this:
[image: Panel-design]

Why is the vAxis not visible the first time?

Comment: this problem occurs when the chart is drawn before its container is visible, need to wait until the panel is shown before drawing the chart -- is there more you can share, specifically how the panels are loaded?

Comment: @WhiteHat Hey White hat, the panels are shown by setting the display property from none to block. So if i click the link to the panel section, the active class will bind to the sections HTML-Element and then the display property changes.

I did the width/height workaround to generate them properly responsive. If i click the link two times in a row the chart loads with the vAxis as it should! It is odd that only happens the first time

Comment: right, the first click, it is drawn before the panel is actually visible, and the problem occurs -- on the second click, the panel is already visible, so the chart draws properly -- will you please share the code that changes the display property?

Comment: @WhiteHat The Graph will be drawn after the user clicks on the link to change the Tab-Panel. The display property is passed by the css-class w--tab-active. I edited the question for you to see. So it is a simple css override. The chart itself is rendered without problems. I also got no problems in my development console in both Firefox and Chrome. It is only the vAxis not showing the first time i reclick a panel to change the Tab. I guess it has something to do with the Tab-Panel but i couldn't find out anything yet by delaying, etc..

Comment: do you have code somewhere that adds / removes the `w--tab-active` css class on the elements?

Comment: @WhiteHat i am using Webflow as design-framework which has an option to create this Tab-Panel structure. The function is comparable to the Bootsrap-Tab-Panels.

Comment: is there an "on shown" event? similar to bootstrap's `'shown.bs.tab'` -- this is where you should draw the chart -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558808/5090771) for an example...