# Vertical axis labels not appearing on first load of google charts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-visualization

I am trying to generate some google charts , specifically a line chart, and i'm having a problem where when I generate the chart for the first time it renders fine but it doesn't have any labels on the y axis. If I regenerate the chart without reloading the page the y axis labels appear.

No Labels: https://i.stack.imgur.com/by7J1.png
Labels:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYMcv.png

And Code

```
                var chartTitle = "Account Manager Performance (" + managerUser + ")";
            var options = {
                title: chartTitle,
                width: 900,
                height: 500,
                hAxis: {
                    slantedText: true,
                    type: 'category'
                },
                pointSize: 5

            };


            var acctManagerTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            if (budgetValue != -1) {
                acctManagerTable.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                acctManagerTable.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
                acctManagerTable.addColumn('number', 'BP');
                acctManagerTable.addColumn('number', 'Commission');
                acctManagerTable.addColumn('number', 'Budget');
                acctManagerTable.addRows(acctManagerData);

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('acct_manager_graph_div'));

            chart.draw(acctManagerTable, options);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: is it possible when the chart is drawn for the first time, it's container is hidden? check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944593/5090771)...

Comment: Yes this was it, I was generating the chart and putting it in the container without the div being visible. Switching them around solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was generating the graph before making the container visible switching the order from

```
                    //Function that draws google visualisation
                    load_page_data(response.Message);
                    $('#listed_v_sold_graph_div').css("display", "block");
```

To

```
                    $('#listed_v_sold_graph_div').css("display", "block");
                    //Function that draws google visualisation
                    load_page_data(response.Message);
```

, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944593/5090771

Comment: Is there a way "not to show" the Y-Axis? How can I achieve that?